# Synchronized object not showing in Journey Builder Entry Data

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, contactbuilder

I'm trying to update a journey and pull some extra data from SF into the DE of the journey which then can be used for personalisation.

I have created new version of the journey and I want to add specific object but I don't see this as an option on the Entry Data (Step 4).
The field I need is synchronised in Contact Builder and I can see it on the synchronised DE. I've also checked if it's available under the Contact Data in a Decision split for example and it is.

However, I can't see it on the Entry Data options though.

A note on that: the object is not linked to the same object which I'm using as an Entry Source. For example my entry source object is linked to the Contacts but the missing object is linked to a different group (User). I don't see the option to create a relationships in any of the Attribute groups.

The goal is to have this field data available into the journey Data Extension and use it for a dynamic content with AMPscript. I know I can pull the data form the synchronised DE with Lookup function but I'm not sure how to match it with the customer so I know it's for the same customer.

I hope that make sense. Thank you

[image: Journey Builder Entry Data]

Comment: If it's not in any way related to the object you're using in the entry, it won't be available there. AMPscript lookups is your best choice. What should be the logic to display User info based on Contact info?

Comment: Thank you @zuzannamj the logic is that it will make it easy to use for a dynamic content that I'm trying to show. Instead of using multiple variables I can only use two. Basically I have some user guides to display based on vehicle Make/Model. The issue is that the Make is not available within the object I use but only the Model which makes it more difficult as the variations are a lot more where the Make are only two types. I think with AMPscript should work but I'm not sure how to check if the value is for the correct customer.

Comment: If you understand how this data is related, then it should not be a problem to make a connection between a customer and a vehicle and display it using AMPscript lookups

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Syncrhonized Data vs. SF Data Entry**

The Synchronized Data Extensions aren't relevant for SF Data Journey Entires. You can only use the data that is linked through relationships set up in Sales/Service Cloud. So no matter if you have the object synchronized or not it can only be pulled to the entry data if it is linked there.

**Relationship in Data Designer**

Adding a relationship in Data Designer won't work as well as the relationships are directly taken from Sales/Service Cloud and it needs to be linked there.

**Pulling Data using AMPscript**

As you already mentioned this would be possible but only if the data is related somehow and shares some information that can be used for a lookup.
If you are unsure you should talk to the architect who set up the Sales/Service Cloud data model and see if there is a relationship of that data and how this can be used. This is necessary so you don't mix up some data that just seems to be linked.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. That make complete sense so the best to do will be to check if the AMPscript will work. I explained more in my comment above why I'm trying to do here.